# Solution to LDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why some linear differential equations have different solutions by different methods? I have come across  $$0.25y" + ~y =1.5\cos(0.5x) -7\sin(7.5x)$$ This LDE have two solutions by undetermined coefficient method and variation of parameters method, so why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Maybe you can add the details of the two methods, so we can determine your issues. I get the same result with those two methods.

Comment: If you are saying that you get two **different** solutions by using those two different methods, that is simply not true!  Of course, as a second order D.E. there will be two "undetermined constants" in it.  It may be that two very different *looking* solutions are really the same if you change the constants and, perhaps, use trig identities.

Comment: Please show us these "different" solutions and we will show you that they are either wrong or identical.

Comment: I have solved by 2 methods and I checked it on online differential equations solver - wolfram and emath . Wolfram gives answer that I got from variation of parameters method and emath gives answer by undetermined coefficient method. The answer is y(x) = c_2 sin(2 x) + c_1 cos(2 x) + sin(1.5 x) sin(2 x) + 0.6 sin(2 x) sin(2.5 x) + cos(1.5 x) cos(2 x) + 0.6 cos(2.5 x) cos(2 x) + 1.27273 sin(5.5 x) cos(2 x) - 0.736842 sin(9.5 x) cos(2 x) + 1.27273 sin(2 x) cos(5.5 x) + 0.736842 sin(2 x) cos(9.5 x) by wolfram. And c1cos(2x)+c2sin(2x)+(112/209)sin(15x/2)+(8/5)cos(x/2) by emath. And I confirmed it.

Answer (score 0):

I get same solution with both methods:
$$y=\frac{560 \sin{\left( \frac{15 x}{2}\right) }+1672 \cos{\left( \frac{x}{2}\right) }}{1045}+\mathit{C_2} \sin{\left( 2 x\right) }+\mathit{C_1} \cos{\left( 2 x\right) }$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: At first you must solve the equation $$\frac{1}{4}y''+y=0$$ by the ansatz $$y=e^{\lambda x}$$